# Error de mysqli_real_escape_string() y bucle foreach al enviar formulario de tipo checkbox en base de datos mediante PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Intento asignar permisos a un grupo de usuarios y para ello
he capturado la id del grupo de usuarios recibida mediante GET en la página *grupos.php*,

Tambien he intentado crear un array (a través del atributo *name* de los checkbox) que almacene los ids de los permisos.
No consigo que el bucle foreach recorra el array y haga la inserción en la base de datos. Además, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` me muestra un error a pesar de tener 2 parámetros.

Estos son los errores que se me muestran:

Primer error

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\yaunde-main\php\asignarPermisos.php on line 16

Segundo error:

> Salta en el else diciendo que No se ha podido asignar los permisos al
> grupo

Adjunto el código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>

        <!--**PAGINA permisosChex.php -->
         //este archivo contiene la conexion a la base datos y verifica el usuario que ha iniciado sesion
      
        include("verificarSesion.php");

        //notificacion: se encargara de mostrar los mensajes de error o éxito de la operación, si se registra al usuario o surge algún problema

        $notificacion['exito'] = array(
           'exitoso' => false, //false=> el mensaje es de error, true=> el mensaje es de exito
           'mensaje' => array()// aquí irá el mensaje que vamos a mostrar
        );

        if (isset($_POST)){

            $id_grupo_usuarios = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['id_grupo_usuarios']);
            $id_permiso =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, is_array($_POST['permisos']));

            if (is_array($id_permiso) == true) {
                foreach($id_permiso as $selected){
                    $consulta = "INSERT INTO tiene_asignado (id_grupo, id_permisos) values ($id_grupo_usuarios, $selected)";

                            if($conexion->query($consulta) === TRUE) {
                                $notificacion['exitoso'] = true;
                                $notificacion['mensaje'] = "Los permisos se han insertado correctamente";

                            } else {

                                $notificacion['exitoso'] = false;
                                $notificacion['mensaje'] = "No se ha podido asignar los permisos $selected al grupo"; //el mensaje que mostraremos al usuario

                            }
                }

           } else {

              $notificacion['exito'] = false;// mensaje de error
              $notificacion['mensaje'] = "No se ha podido asignar los permisos al grupo";
    
           }

       echo json_encode($notificacion);
        
        } else {
           header("location: inicio.php"); 
           "NO SE HA ENVIADO NADA";
        }

    //cerramos la conexión a la base de datos
    $conexion->close();
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ang3les96 : está bien que edites la ortografía, pero evita hacer esto cuando se trata de comentarios en el código. Al fin y al cabo, _es parte del código_.

Answer (score 0):

La función `is_array()` devuelve `true/false` y eso es lo que estas pasando como segundo argumento a `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Adicionalmente, tampoco puedes pasar un array a  `mysqli_real_escape_string`, debes aplicar el escape sobre cada elemento al iterarlo.

```html
$id_grupo_usuarios = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['id_grupo_usuarios']);
$permisos = $_POST['permisos'];

if (is_array($permisos) == true) {
        foreach($permisos as $selected){
                $selected = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $selected);
                $consulta = "INSERT INTO tiene_asignado (id_grupo, id_permisos) values ($id_grupo_usuarios, $selected)";

                if($conexion->query($consulta) === TRUE) {
                        $notificacion['exitoso'] = true;
                        $notificacion['mensaje'] = "Los permisos se han insertado correctamente";
                }else {
                        $notificacion['exitoso'] = false;
                        $notificacion['mensaje'] = "No se ha podido asignar los permisos $selected al grupo"; //el mensaje que mostraremos al usuario
                }
         }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda, me ha funcionado el codigo!!